# How to exclude wordpress from magento root

Tags: wordpress, magento, backup, fishpig

I have a magento store running on name.pippo.com

Now I am considering to install wordpress for blogging.

Since I would like to integrate magento + wordpress as a fully integrate system (maybe with magento fishpig extension), i would like to knwo how to obtain same result but installing wordpress in a subfolder of my TLD, i.e. www.pippo.com/wp

can i Do that?

The main reason is to have both system separate and avoiding magento system backup to back up wordpress too. I would like to have magento on its own, in a thirdlevel domain keeping the magento installation as much clean as I can.

thank you very much, I hope i was clear. I appreciate any advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but it makes no sense and would take a bit of hacking together. This is one of those situations where if you have to ask how to do it, you probably won't be able to do it.

My advice would be to integrate WordPress normally and just have WP as part of your backup.

Keep WP as lean as possible, install few plugins and only have 1 theme installed. If you want to be really secure, limit access to your WP Admin by IP address and ensure all permissions are set restrictively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can made sub folder in your TLD and as you know the fishpig wordpress integration in this extension you can make a separate database for wordpress or you can merge wordpress database to magento database and you can take both backup separately.